# Xbox with dvi and constantly turns off by itself

Tags: xbox-360

I have a Xbox 360 that has a broken HDMI jack with no sound (DVI), but still allows me to play on hi-def. Another problem with it is that it constantly shuts off by itself, reverts itself to 480x640 resolution until it heats up to a point. I have yet to find out how to fix it, and was wondering if others have had this kind of problems?

Comment: `"until it heats up to a point."` What happens when it reaches "a point"?

Comment: It stops shuting off and stays on 720p (720 is the highest I can play on with my tv)

Comment: So once it heats up, you have to cut power to it to shut it down, and then on next boot-up it's back to 480x640 resolution?

Comment: No when I first come I to play I turn it on and it is on 720p (because I got it heated up and played skyrim yesterday) but in about 5 minutes it turns off by itself and goes back to 640x480 (sorry I got that wrong the other couple times).so I turn it back on and go back to 720 and it shuts off again going back to 640x480 and I wash and repeat until it gets to a "heated up" point and stops shuting off